# How to plot line graph with repetitive x axis lables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset in which the x axis labels are not unique and are non-numberic. Here's a sample:

```
0   )
0   )
0   .
0   )
1   )
420 )
474 )
518 )
567 )
580 )
```

When I plot this with ggplot2 using this code:

```
ggplot(data=Figure3b, aes(x=Bracket, y=Counts)) + geom_line()
```

I get this:

[image: ggplot2_output]

Whereas I am after something like this:

[image: desired_output]

As far as I can tell, it's somehow grouping all the values with the same x axis label whereas I want it to just plot the points in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an index to your parens and then plot

```
dat$index <- 1:nrow(dat)
ggplot(dat, aes(index, x)) + geom_line(lwd=2, col="blue") + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels=dat$y) + xlab("brackets")
```

Data looks like:

```
> head(dat)
#        x y index
#    1   0 )     1
#    2   0 .     2
#    3   0 )     3
#    4   1 )     4
#    5 420 )     5
#    6 474 )     6
```

[image]